# what am I doing wrong here? program loops non stop

Tags: c, clock, fibonacci

This is a C program with iterative Fibonacci using clock() to time how long it takes to get the nth Fibonacci number. The program loops non stop. I know that the equations are right because I was able to run the program correctly w/o the clock function. Any help is appreciated!

```
#include<time.h>
#include<sys/file.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main ( )
{
  int j=1, fib, n, i=1, k=0;
  int choice;
  float x,y,z;

  x = clock(); //start clock

  printf("input the fib number you want: ");
  scanf("$d", &n);

  while (k <=n)
  {
    fib = i + j;
    i = j;
    j = fib;
    ++k;

    printf( "The fib number is %d\n ", fib);
  }

  y =clock(); // end clock
  z = (y - x) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

  printf("\n\nThe execution time was: %.15f", z);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please, please, please learn to properly indent your code (not only here, but in your actual source as well). Tabs and spaces are free, and make code so much easier to read and maintain. Learning to use a debugger might be a useful skill to acquire, too. :-) Also, as an FYI: Your starting call to `clock()` should be after the `scanf()`, or you're including the time spent waiting for input into your timing.

Comment: I bet the clock resolution would not let you see a difference of even a single tick: it takes only 47 iterations to overflow a 32-bit integer,and only 90 iterations or so to overflow a 64-bit long.

Comment: Its hard to properly indent when using Linux. I am only a beginner C coder(less than a month). Sorry about that. I have changed the clock starting to after the input and fixed the typo %d on scanf which fixed the loop. Now I need some input on the clock because its staying at 0.00000000 or is it supposed to be like that for iterative fib?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`scanf("$d", &n);` needs to be `scanf("%d", &n);`. Chances are, whatever random value `n` gets when your program starts is making your loop condition fail.

As mentioned by @dasblinkenlight in the comments, you should start the clock **after** the user input if you want a useful measurement.

Additionally, though most books don't seem to cover it, checking the return value of `scanf()` is a good idea as it can catch typos like yours above (thanks @WilliamPursell). Something like the following would work:

```
if( scanf( "whatever random and incorrect format string", &n ) != 1 ) {
  /* exit with error message */
}
```

From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/#return):

> On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument
>   list successfully filled. This count can match the expected number of
>   items or be less (even zero) due to a matching failure, a reading
>   error, or the reach of the *end-of-file*.
>
> If a reading error happens or the *end-of-file* is reached while
>   reading, the proper indicator is set (**feof** or **ferror**). And, if either
>   happens before any data could be successfully read, `EOF` is returned.
>
> If an encoding error happens interpreting wide characters, the
>   function sets **errno** to `EILSEQ`.

Comment: +1 Please also mention that starting the clock before user input is a sure way to get random results :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That's certainly a problem!

Comment: Also mention checking the return value of scanf: `if( scanf( "whatever random and incorrect format string", &n ) != 1 ) { /* exit with error message */;}` would catch the problem

Comment: Thanks! got it to work :) But the clock doesnt seem to work >.< I put the x = clock(); right after scanf("%d", &n). The loop is gone but timer of the clock isnt working..

Comment: What do you mean? [It works fine for me](http://pastie.org/private/ohdrz5axzhrzj4ri48jw).

Comment: I kind of want to keep it simple since my professor only wanted us to put iterative fib with a clock function to tell how long it would take to get results.

Comment: I tried again and still got 0.0000.

http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/5089/itfib.png

Comment: Perhaps try using a `double` instead of a `float`? **EDIT** Actually, [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/) suggests using a `clock_t` type.

Comment: I tried that example using clockt_t. I still got the same result. Do you think it has something to do with the Linux?

Comment: Honestly not sure. You might have better luck asking about that specific problem in another question. Also, if this one's solved, please accept this answer. Thanks!